# how to Include a SQL table inside an html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make a table inside my existing page displaying a list of movie's and the genres of those movies.

This is my Movies page. My index.php file creates the connection and has the database credentials already in play.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Courses</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navtop">
        <div>
            <h1>BB.com</h1>
            <a href="profile.php">Profile</a>
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            <a href="home.php">Home</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <h1><u> Movies </u> </h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper"</div>
            <h1>Genres</h1>
            <div class="data">
                
                <select name="books">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>Horror</option>
                    <option>Romance</option>
                    <option>Thriller</option>
                    <option>Detective</option>
                    <option>Comedy</option>
                    <option>Drama</option>
                    <option>Spy</option>
                    <option>Fantasy</option>
                    <option>Sc-Fi</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="b1" class="submit"/>
            </div>
            
            <table>
                
                
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have an external file that does display the table information incase i have to include it in the table/form.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Admin";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
     
                 
                

$sql = "SELECT mv, genre FROM movies";
if ($result->num_rows > 1)
    echo "<table width=100% border=1>";
 
echo "<tr><td>Movie</td><td>Genre</td></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["mv"]. "</td><td>" . $row["genre"]. "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Any pointers? I'm fairly new to this and can't find relevant information online.
Thanks

Comment: Are you simply looking for [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), or what exactly is the question?

Comment: yes sorry include it.

Comment: Then just put an include or require statement into the place where you currently have the "empty" table. (The table tags should be removed, since you are creating them in the second script already - and you don't want `<table><table>...` as result.)

Comment: Please note that setting up a MySQL root user with no password is okay for LOCAL development only. Do not do this for production.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Admin";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT mv, genre FROM movies";
if ($result->num_rows > 1){
?>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Movie</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
        ?>
           <tr>
               <td><?php echo  $row["mv"];?></td>
               <td><?php echo  $row["genre"];?></td>
           </tr>
        <?php
        } // end while loop
        ?>
    </table>
<?php
} // end if
?>
```